# commandButton actionListener not called when disabled property is false

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**Given**: a primefaces 5.3 application with the following xhtml

```
    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:messages id="serversMessages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:selectOneListbox value="#{servers.model.selectedServer}" style="min-width:300px">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{servers.onServerSelected}" update=":form" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{servers.model.servers}" var="srv" itemValue="#{srv.serverInfoId}" itemLabel="#{srv.name}" />
        </p:selectOneListbox>

        <p:column><p:inputText value="#{servers.model.edit.name}" /></p:column>
        <p:commandButton id="newServerBtn" actionListener="#{servers.onNewServerClicked}" value="New" update=":form"></p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="updServerBtn" disabled="#{empty servers.model.selectedServer}" actionListener="#{servers.onSaveClicked}" value="Save" update=":form"></p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="tmpServerBtn" actionListener="#{servers.onTempClicked}" value="Temp2" update=":form"></p:commandButton>

    </h:form>
```

**When**: I click on the updServerBtn (it's enabled when an item in the list has been selected)

**Expectation**: The backing bean method will be called.

**But actually**: The backing bean method is NOT called.

**Observations**:

1. If I remove the disabled property the backing bean is called.
2. The tmpServerBtn invokes a backing bean method.
3. When I click on the updServerBtn, an XHR happens with a 200 response.

**Analysis**:

It would seem like that Primefaces is deciding that it is not worthwhile to call the backing bean method.

**Similar Questions**

Before posting my question, I did find this post here:

[commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked)

When I remove the disabled attribute of the updServerBtn, the backing bean method **does** get invoked.  This suggests to me that the possible causes of problems in the above post, probably don't apply.

Comment: When I switch the backing bean to be SessionScoped the method is being invoked.

Comment: When the scope is ViewScoped or RequestScoped the method is NOT being invoked.

Comment: I added logging to the constructor and the readResolve method.  No signs it's being called though.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your problem is that when you select a server from the `selectOneListBox`, your button is not updated and thus, disabled attribute is not recalculated.

Try to change the `update` attribute of `<p:ajax>` change event. Instead of update `:form` try to update `@form`.

Comment: Nope, button was clickable. A disabled button is unclickable in first place. If you can't be certain or can't test/reproduce the problem on your own, better post a comment.

Comment: You are right @BalusC